# Limit number of download on Google store

Tags: google-play

I am currently working on a beta version of an android app, and I need to release it while controlling the number of people using it to around 500 max.

Is it possible to limit how many time an app I put on the Google Store can be downloaded?

Comment: Oops, my research did not pop this one. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. Glad you found what you were looking for. :)